# distutils setup install --build-base doesn't work

Tags: python, build, installation, distutils

This doesn't work:

```
python setup.py install --build-base=foo
```

How can I tell distutils where to take the built files from for installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found [this bug report](http://bugs.python.org/issue1011113) in python's Issue Tracker. It suggests:

```
python setup.py build -b <somedir> install
```

And it works for me.

Comment: That’s strange.  A glance at the code makes me think that both code snippets should work.  I’ll investigate the bug more when I get time.